# Can I specify an init view scale for portrait and one for landscape for the iPad?

Tags: jquery, ipad, screen-orientation

I have a meta rule added to my site so ipad scales everything down, I only want this to happen in landscape mode, when the user changes the orientation to portrait or if the user loads the page in portrait mode I want the scale to change to 1 and the whole page to scale to fit.

I have used this code.

```
if(ipad){
            window.onorientationchange = function() {

                var orientation = window.orientation;
                var location = window.location.href;
                gallery.rescale();
                if (orientation === 0) {
                    $('.galleria-thumbnails .galleria-image:nth-child(5n+5)').removeClass('last-thumb');
                    $('.galleria-thumbnails .galleria-image:nth-child(4n+4)').addClass('last-thumb');
                    $('.galleria-thumbnails .galleria-image:nth-child(4n+1)').addClass('next-thumb');
                    $('.galleria-thumbnails .galleria-image:nth-child(1)').removeClass('next-thumb');



                    $("body").addClass("portrait");

                } else if (orientation === 90) {
                    $('.galleria-thumbnails .galleria-image:nth-child(5n+5)').addClass('last-thumb');
                    $('.galleria-thumbnails .galleria-image:nth-child(4n+4)').removeClass('last-thumb')
                    $('.galleria-thumbnails .galleria-image:nth-child(4n+1)').removeClass('next-thumb');

                    $("body").removeClass("portrait");                      

                } else if (orientation === -90) {
                    $('.galleria-thumbnails .galleria-image:nth-child(5n+5)').addClass('last-thumb');
                    $('.galleria-thumbnails .galleria-image:nth-child(4n+4)').removeClass('last-thumb')
                    $('.galleria-thumbnails .galleria-image:nth-child(4n+1)').removeClass('next-thumb');

                    $("body").removeClass("portrait");


                } else if (orientation === 180) {
                    $('.galleria-thumbnails .galleria-image:nth-child(5n+5)').removeClass('last-thumb');
                    $('.galleria-thumbnails .galleria-image:nth-child(4n+4)').addClass('last-thumb');
                    $('.galleria-thumbnails .galleria-image:nth-child(4n+1)').addClass('next-thumb');
                    $('.galleria-thumbnails .galleria-image:nth-child(1)').removeClass('next-thumb');

                    $("body").addClass("portrait");

                }
            }       
        }
```

This enables the thumbnails per row to change between portrait and landscape and it works well.

I've tried to add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.85" />` on each orientation change rule but it's not working.

Any ideas as to why? 
I would love a solution to this issue or to know if there is one.

Thanks very much for your help

Comment: I've figured it out i needed to add / remove portrait when the page loads otherwise the orientation isn't correctly rescaled.

Comment: You should put your comment in an "answer" and mark it as the answer to your question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out i needed to add / remove portrait when the page loads otherwise the orientation isn't correctly rescaled.

***Thanks teewuane